# Given two integers left and right that represent the range [left, right], return the bitwise AND of all numbers in this range, inclusive

Tags: java, time-complexity, bit-manipulation, bitwise-and

Why is it failing, Is there any other thing that we can add to the same logic to make it correct.

It fails at left=6 right=7

Here is the code snippet:

```
class Solution {
    public static int log2(int N)
    {

        // calculate log2 N indirectly
        // using log() method
        int result = (int)(Math.log(N) / Math.log(2));

        return result;
    }
    public int rangeBitwiseAnd(int left, int right) {
        int res=1;
        int lower=log2(left);
        int higher = log2(right);
        // System.out.print(higher);
        if(left==right)
        return left;
        if(lower != higher){
            return left&(int)Math.pow(2,higher);
        }
        else{
            return (int)Math.pow(2,higher);
        }
           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is incorrect; it is not sufficient to only check the most significant bits. Instead, you need to find the longest matching prefix in the binary representation of the endpoints. In addition, the `Integer.highestOneBit` utility method can be used instead of floating-point math.

```java
public int rangeBitwiseAnd(int left, int right) {
    int leftHighest = Integer.highestOneBit(left), rightHighest = Integer.highestOneBit(right);
    if (leftHighest != rightHighest || left == 0 || right == 0) return 0;
    return leftHighest | rangeBitwiseAnd(left ^ leftHighest, right ^ leftHighest);
}
```

Alternatively, an iterative solution:

```java
public int rangeBitwiseAnd(int left, int right) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 1 << 30; i > 0; i >>= 1) {
        int ltest = left & i;
        if (ltest != (right & i)) break;
        res |= ltest;
    }
    return res;
}
```